# Take the url from the input and get the value from it, then display it in the input

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

The /fetch/ route should contain (serve to the client) a web page (text/html; charset=UTF-8).
It has the following requirements:
A. Must contain one input field with the identifier (id) inp
B. Should contain one button button with identifier (id) bt
C. When this button is clicked, the script on this page should use fetch to fetch the address that is entered in the input field at the time of the click (the address will be entered by the automatic tester)
D. Having received the result returned by this address, the script should place that result in the inp field instead of the value it previously had.

I created a page, I'm attaching the code. But how to make a fetch call to the input content and so that it then passes the value to the field, I can’t understand. Tell me please.

```
'"<input type="text" id="inp">
<button id="bt"></button>

<script>
   fetch()  
  .then(  
    function(response) {  
        return response.text;  
      }

</script>"'
```

Comment: That seems as homework to me. SO is not meant to solve anyone's homework or coding challenges. In order for us to provide some help, we would require you to share what you have done so far in attempt to solve your issue/task. And here's the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) for the Fetch API.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch  On the button click you need to get the value that is in your input field. You then pass this to the fetch function, and then when you get the response back you need to put that into the input field. Approach it methodically - do one part first, then move onto the next

Comment: @Craicerjack <script>
    function login(){
            var login = document.getElementById('inp').value;
         

            fetch(login).then(
               response => {
                  return response.text();
               }
            ).then(
               text => {
                  document.getElementById('inp').innerHTML = text;
               }
            );
         }
    </script>
I tried to do that. Got the value via id. But did fetch set him up correctly ?

Comment: What is triggering the login function?